# Чем плох или опасен удалённый MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, почему хостеры не хотят предоставлять возможность удаленно подключаться к MySQL, скажем, что бы работала репликация, либо для простого подключения к базе данных?
Это опасно, это нагружает сервер, или создает трафик?

Answer (score 1):

Делать удаленную БД, по православному, можно только тогда, когда ты ведешь список разрешенных IP адресов. Идея в том, что к вашей удаленной БД могут подключиться только те IP адреса, которым вы это разрешили. Иначе ваши БД будут тупо брутфорсить ( тоже самое, в целом, актуально и для ftp, ssh ). Соответственно - тупо разрешить не вариант, а список IP адресов - лишний геморрой для хостера, причем, судя по всему, серьезный. К тому-же, нередко, уровень пользователей услугами хостеров, как и, собственно, самих хостеров, мягко говоря, желает лучшего. Это если говорить о вопросах безопасности.

Если-же говорить о производительности, то, естественно, запрос к локальному серверу БД будет работать быстрее чем запрос к удаленному.

Еще стоит добавить - чаще всего, если, все-таки, ваш проект действительно нуждается в удаленной БД ( обычно, естественно, это несколько серверов ), ему не место у хостера.

Comment: У хостера стоит Cpanel которая в комплекте умеет делать такое, разрешать доступ к своим базам с определенных IP. Тоесть как бы и геморра никакого, все на совести клиента. Но вот функция отключена.
По поводу того, что не место, согласен. Но есть определенные удобства работы именно у этого хостера, да и служба поддержки характеризуется мною положительно, но вот этот момент просто был непонятен для меня.

Comment: Если по-православому, то пусть брутфорсят, чего в этом плохого? denyhosts и fail2ban не вчера изобрели, как и авторизацию по X.509-сертификатам.

Comment: @drdaeman - вы безусловно правы, но жизнь гавно... если вы поняли о чем я :)

Comment: Это да, что есть то есть…

Answer (score 0):

Думаю не опасно, если поставить хороший пароль, сервер будет нагружаться как и на локалхосте, трафик конечно создает, но в бд основном хранятся текстовые данные, и если при каждом обращении не будете дергать целую таблицу, то нормально. Для репликации и для простого администрирования базы вполне нормально удаленный доступ, вот если сайт допустим будет работать на удалённом бд, то разница конечно будет в виде тормозов загрузки страницы.

Comment: Я имею в виду работу сайта, а не просто администрирование. Понятно, что там передаются незашифрованные данные, но и ничего страшного. Пароли все равно хешированы. Какие еще есть подводные камни? И почему все же на хостинге не добиться удаленки на базу, если ничего такого страшного тут нет.

Comment: ну допустим на странице 10 запросов к мускулу, пинг с обработкой запроса до сервера мускул 50мс, и получается 10x50=500мс для одного лишь получения данных, + к этому работа php скрипта и отдача в браузер клиенту. Вот эта заторможенность будет чувствоваться на удаленном сайте.

Comment: это понятно, но больше никаких препятствий же нет? Опять же, почему тогда не дают хостеры этого делать. Разве что на это время скрипт ждет отдачи мускула и висит долго в памяти...

Comment: Ну возможны очереди в мускуле, если допустим на сайт было одновременно несколько вызовов. Ну, а так, кроме как паранойии хостеров в этом я не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

У хороших хостеров есть возможность подключать вашу базу к удаленной т.е. у вас должен быть другой dns с открытым доступом к базе. В phpmyadmin пункт синхронизация. Использую [reg.ru](http://reg.ru) и там оно есть.

Хочу прояснить, это НЕ реклама [reg.ru](http://reg.ru). Всего лишь отписался по тому как обстоят дела на этом хостере.